# SiriKit Intents UI - Payment Domain - Center Area is repeated three times

Tags: swift, swift3, siri, sirikit

I am using SiriKit for Payment Domain and when user say **"Send 10 $ to Ronoldo**", my custom UI is shown. 

Although there is only 1 label in my custom view, SiriKit shows the IntentsUI as it has three same label as image below.

I think my view is repeated 3 times. Can you help please?

[image: Label with text "Kat..." is repeated as three times]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. My custom Siri UI conforms to the INUIHostedViewControlling protocol and it defines **configureView** function for providing the custom interface. It is called many times for each parameter for my view controller, I checked the correct parameter and return my controller's view size only 1 time.

Hope this helps someone.

```
       func configureView(for parameters: Set<INParameter>, of interaction: INInteraction, interactiveBehavior: INUIInteractiveBehavior, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: @escaping (Bool, Set<INParameter>, CGSize) -> Void) {

                //.... other codes....

                if (parameters.count > 0) {
                        let startIntentDescriptionParameter = INParameter(for: INSendPaymentIntent.self,
                                                                          keyPath: "currencyAmount")

                        if parameters.contains(startIntentDescriptionParameter) {
                            return completion(true, parameters, self.desiredSize)
                        }
                    }

               return completion(false, parameters, CGSize.zero)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in one of my project.I used following method instead of the configureView function for providing the custom interface.

```
func configure(with interaction: INInteraction!, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: ((CGSize) -> Void)!) {
    // your code....
     completion(self.desiredSize)

  }
```

and by using this method mine problem was solved I hope it works for u too.